# How is an object converted into a class object?

Tags: python, python-internals

How is an `object` transformed into a class object? For example:

```
>>> object
<type 'object'>

>>> class NewClass:
...     pass
```

If someone were to start with:

```
>>> o=object
```

What would need to be done in the interpreter to "convert" that object into `NewClass`? (Or is it not possible to do without the class syntax?).

Comment: Where do you imagine objects *are converted* to class objects?

Comment: I don't understand what you are getting at with this question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I thought creating a class is the same as doing `class NewClass(object):`, where it converts from the object type?

Comment: @David542 That's inheritance, not conversion. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That is not a conversion from `object`; it's giving `object` as the parent class from which to inherit.

Comment: @David542 no, that is not what the class definition statement does at all. `class NewClass(object): ...` says "create a class NewClass that inherits from object"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see, thanks for the explanation. Is it possible then to "create that class" from the interpreter without using the `class NewClass: pass` statement? I'm basically just trying to understand what python is doing behind the scenes to create the new class from a base object/class.

Comment: class objects are created using a metaclass, a class of a class. Unless you specifically choose an alternate, that will be `type`, and you can create classes dynamically using the three argument form of `type`. So, `NewClass = type("NewClass", (object,), {})` would be the equivalent thing to your class definition. Note, classes aren't *created from* a base class. They *inherit* from them.

Comment: @David542 some good reading about what goes on during class creation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot simply "convert" an object of one class into another; they are, by default, incompatible types.  Rather, you write a conversion method for the old class that returns your desired object of the new class.  For instance ...

```
class new_obj:
    def __init__(self, value=13):
        self.value = value


class old_obj:
    def __init__(self, value=7):
        self.value = value

    def to_new(self):
        return new_obj(value * value)
```

Your "conversion" sequence would then be

```
old_thing = old_obj(5)
new_thing = old_thing.to_new()
```

Comment: I don't *think* that is what the OP is asking, but it isn't super clear.